# Encrypting a Postgres column at the application level using AWS KMS

Tags: postgresql, encryption, amazon-kms, pgcrypto

**Problem**

I need to store encrypted data in a Postgres column.

I know of [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html), however I haven't used it before and don't have a lot of time to research and understand it (which I'd like to, given the data I will be storing in the column).

However, I do have a fairly solid and practical understanding of [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/).

My immediate path of least resistance is to handle the encryption at the application level.

**Proposed Solution**

- Encrypt the plain text data using the KMS SDK.
- Save the encrypted data into the column via the ORM.
- Retrieve the encrypted data from the database via the ORM.
- Decrypt the encrypted data using the KMS SDK.

The key would be secured in KWS using EC2 IAM roles.

**Good to know:**

- This particular table is not queried often, so performance is not my biggest concern in this instance.
- My needs are more particular than simply using Encryption at Rest with RDS.

**Question:**

- Are there any potential flaws in handling the encryption of database data in this manner?